# Is Michael Mamaril in Sanctuary always around?

Tags: borderlands-2

I haven't been able to find him,

> since the lifting of Sanctuary.

I am on PS3 with no internet connection at this point, not sure if it matters.

Comment: I suggest editing your question.  Big spoiler there.

Comment: @DavidStarkey The game's been out for months.  There's no reason to to spoiler that at all.

Comment: @fbueckert You should always try to hide spoilers.  You never know how long people will wait until they play a game.  Perhaps they are waiting until the price drops to a certain point.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Arqade works a bit differently.  We've discussed spoilers, and unless they're massive spoilers, they don't belong in questions.  You're on the Internet; you're going to get spoiled  Further reading: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7135/20456

Comment: @fbueckert - I suppose it depends on your definition of "massive spoiler". In regards to the one above, I consider that to be a pretty big one.

Comment: @fbueckert Imagine with me: I'm on the internet looking for an answer to a question about this game I'm playing.  It's kinda old so I think finding an answer should be easy.  I find this "Arqade" site, surely a site devoted to answering questions for games can ignore spoilers.  I don't want to type a whole question, so I type the character name and I'll search for the question I want.  Oh look, ends up he dies at major plot twist in the game.  I'll be sure to never use that Arqade site again if I care about spoilers.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Dude, you're *on the internet*.  If you don't want to be spoiled, don't be here.  Especially for a game that's been out for months.

Comment: @fbueckert Translation: Never use Arquade (or the internet in general) if you have anything (game, movie, TV show, etc.) that you have not finished.  I realize the internet if full of spoilers, but a website with the sole purpose of answering questions about video games should be able to be as spoiler free as possible.  When this happens, you find that gamers WANT to ask questions here because they know they won't be spoiler heavy.  Users COME BACK to get answers.  It's just good logic to limit spoilers whenever possible.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Spoilers get in the way of asking good questions.  If you have to re-route around major plot points to make sure people don't get spoiled, you're going to ask a pretty vague question.  Arqade's goal is to have ask questions, *and get expert answers*.  Preserving user's feeling is a secondary (if not tertiary) concern.  If you need to spoil something to properly ask your question, you most definitely should.  Beating around the bush doesn't help anyone at all, least of all the person asking.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading that meta link I posted yesterday.  That's the community stance on spoilers.  You're free to disagree with it, and post your own stance.  But that's how we currently stand in regards to spoilers.

Comment: @fbueckert I agree this to be a discussion for Meta, but the original comment was for the actual question (the part that ends up being listed in all the questions) contained something many people would consider a major spoiler for this game.  If you want to be scrolling through questions and see the the endings for all the games you are playing, that's fine but I'd rather not.  Once I click the question, the spoiler away.  I clicked the question and understand that there may be spoilers tied to it, though we do have functionality to limit this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, he's still hanging around Sanctuary.  The two times I've found him have been after Sanctuary lifts off, in fact.

There was a patch at one point that drastically reduced his spawn rate, so if you were used to his pre-patch spawn rate and then got the patch at one point, that might cause some confusion.

Comment: Do you happen to know what patch it was that changed it? Due to lack of internet at home I cannot update it right now and its been months since I have.

Comment: @Adaysnix, I think it was patched in October 2012.

Comment: @Adaysnix [Here's the list of Borderlands 2 PS3 updates / hot fixes](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=167351), confirming that Michael Mamaril's spawn rate was indeed patched in October 2012.